# WM_PAINT, Java and capturing hidden windows

Tags: java, screen-capture, awtrobot, wm-paint

First a disclaimer, I'm a Java programmer and have almost no idea about the Windows API. So please bear with me.

My goal is to use Java to capture a hidden window. My target platform is Windows. I do understand that the `Robot` class is used for capuring the visible part of the screen. After some browsing, I came across these three links, which seem to be relevant:

- http://www.support.teamdev.com/thread/1930
- http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ui/2006-02/msg00204.html
- http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html

JxCapture is as bloodily expensive as Feng Yuan article is complicated. My question is this, if the gurus in this forum can help me find a reasonable solution. The approach suggested in JxCapture does not seem to be overly complex. Any hints? A visual basic script or some C# code that does this would be a good starting point.

I was of the belief that when the window is hidden, if I send a keypress event or a mouse press event to it, it would force it to redraw itself and hence allow itself to be captured even by `java.awt.Robot`. That was an illusion and it doesn't work.

On the other hand, the message in the JxCapture thread is from the year 2006; could it be that Sun has included such a feature since then and I'm just not aware of it?

Comment: Another relevant article is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830359/capturing-a-window-that-is-hidden-or-minimized

I'm evaluating it right now.