# WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap() doesn't render the image

Tags: c#, rendering, webbrowser-control, drawtobitmap

I have got into a strange situation and couldn't find a reason or resolution to it. I have a utility that creates a jpg image out of an HTML content. It is using WebBrowser.Navigate(url) and WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap() methods.

This utility has been working for a year or more by different clients on their servers. Now, one of them which could get desired images until few weeks ago, getting strange images. The image just shows the URL that I am passing to the Navigate() method. I could render the correct image from the same URL on my local machine. I checked the DocumentText property of the object and the contents was there and all the width and height was OK and no error is generated anywhere. Only the image doesn't make any sense. It is not related to the HTML contents and does the same behavior for all pages.

Does anyone knows what could be changed that caused this issue to happen? Although they have recently upgraded from Server 2008 to 2012, they claim that this rendering stopped before the upgrade. My code has not been touched. The project is built with C# and .NET 4.0.

Any help or comments is appreciated.
Behzad

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351830/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-generating-blank-images-for-few-sites-consistently

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of KB3057839 which has broken DrawToBitmap:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9d690398-1f91-4fbd-82fa-4b663c3b558f/kb3057839-has-broken-windows-forms-controldrawtobitmap-when-called-from-application-launched-from?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissue

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue was introduced using the security update patch "KB3057839" . Microsoft has again released a few set of patches on July 14(Please check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms15-jul.aspx). The patch "KB3070102" resolves the issue and can be downloaded from https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS15-073.