# Take screenshot of div in InternetExplorer

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I am using mshtml.InternetExplorer object within my winforms application to browse a web application. Somehow I **can't** use webbrowser in my solution. Now I need to capture screenshot of a div element inside this web application. I see lots of solutions doing similar functionality using webbrowser's drawtobitmap method but none is using mshtml.InternetExplorer.
Is there way to achieve this functionality ? Is there some way that I can type cast InternetExplorer object into webbrowser?

Comment: Not clear, are you automating an out-of-process `InternetExplorer` object or hosting an in-process instance of `WebBrowser` ActiveX control?

Comment: I am automating an out-of-process InternetExplorer object. I just do process.start(iexplore.exe) & then automating that ie instance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to capture the desired part of the main IE window using [`PrintWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx) Windows API, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834473/1768303). You can get the handle of the window by calling [`IWebBrowser2::HWND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752126.aspx) on the IE object. Some other methods could also help to make this happen:

- [`IWebBrowser2::ClientToWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`IHTMLElement::scrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`IHTMLElement2::getBoundingClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I know this is somewhat late after the question was asked but I implemented exactly the same solution as suggested by you but it is failing randomly on some user' machine.It fails for difft resolution/browser zoom. Isnt there any method like webbrowser's drawtobitmap that will dynamically fetch image given its id ?

Comment: @user435293, consider posting a new question with more details, someone else might be able to help better.