# Take screenshot of full area

Tags: vb.net, winapi, bitmap, screenshot

I am using Visual Basic to get a screenshot of, in this case, the edit control in Notepad:

```
Dim windowHandle = FindWindow("Notepad", Nothing)
windowHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, Nothing, "Edit", Nothing)

Dim clientRect As RECT
GetClientRect(windowHandle, clientRect)

Dim windowDeviceContext = GetDC(windowHandle)
Dim memoryDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(windowDeviceContext)
Dim bitmapHandle = CreateCompatibleBitmap(windowDeviceContext, clientRect.Right, clientRect.Bottom)
Dim selectObjectResult = SelectObject(memoryDeviceContext, bitmapHandle)
Dim bitBltResult = BitBlt(memoryDeviceContext, 0, 0, clientRect.Right, clientRect.Bottom, windowDeviceContext, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY)
Dim bmpScreen As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(bitmapHandle)

bmpScreen.Save(Filepath)
```

This works fine, but as you keep typing, eventually you will get a scrollbar in the edit control. The above code only captures the visible area of the control. Is there a way to get the FULL control area as if there are no scrollbars? I am limited to Visual Basic and Win32 API obviously.

Comment: How is this related to C++?

Comment: Well basically all used functions are C++ WIN32 API which are imported into VB. So it's based on C++ code. But yeah maybe not the best tag.

Comment: And why the VB6 tag?

Comment: No, there isn't. The area hidden behind the scrollbars is not actually displayed, so it cannot be screenshotted. Why do you need a screenshot? Would it be sufficient just to get the text that the control contains?

Comment: @JohnSmith There is no C++ Win32 API (I wish there was). Technically it's a C API. But your code is not written in C++ and neither is your objective, so assuming the correctness of the imports, the C++ has no relevance here.

Comment: @Cody Gray unfortunately this is not sufficient. I need a screenshot to proof a website (notepad is just an example) being in a certain style. Basically what I am asking is how does Snagit do this, because this program can capture a screenshot of the full area.

Comment: If you want to capture a webpage contents from a webbrowser like IE for example, you might need to look at the WM_PRINT(CLIENT) message.

Comment: You can also check the PrintWindow API and the following links as well:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830359/capturing-a-window-that-is-hidden-or-minimized, 
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q161299, 
http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html (Uses hooks)